# Can you target Google Chrome?

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, target

I need to position this update button on www.euroworker.no/order (you'll have to add an item to the cart, use the Kjøp button to add and Handlevogn to view the cart). Works in FF and IE. (Although there is another alignment problems with IE) but not in Chrome or Safari. I had it working before, but the only thing I can think of to do is target safari and Chrome. Is this possible?

Here's the CSS and HTML(Smarty) for you.

HTML(Smarty):

```
    {capture assign="cartUpdate"}

     <div id="cartUpdate"><!--<input type="submit" class="submit" value="{tn _update}" />-->
     <button type="submit" class="submit" id="oppdatersubmit" name="saveFields" title="Oppdater" value="">&nbsp;</button> </div>
    {/capture}
    {assign var="cartUpdate" value=$cartUpdate|@str_split:10000}
    {php}$GLOBALS['cartUpdate'] = $this->get_template_vars('cartUpdate'); $this->assign_by_ref('GLOBALS', $GLOBALS);{/php}

    {form action="controller=order action=update" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" handle=$form id="cartItems"}

CONTENT

{/form}
```

And the CSS:

```
#oppdatersubmit {
 background-image:url(../../upload/oppdater.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:left;
 background-color:none;
 border:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 outline:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
 width:77px;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
 position:absolute;
}

#cartUpdate {
 position:absolute;
 width:160px;
 height:30px;
 left:580px;
 bottom:130px;
}
```

Need to change these for Chrome and Safari.

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is not with chrome or safari... You have wrong nesting of tags ... fix that and then worry about specific browser issues..

Comment: The problem is with spcific browser issues, the system I am working with is not perfect and I can't change everything. This is what I have to do to make it work, we all know this isn't an exact science, I really do need to just target chrome.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    /*Chrome CSS here*/

    #cartUpdate {
        position:absolute;
        width:160px;
        height:30px;
        left:660px;
        bottom:40px;
    }
}
```

Fixed the problem :)

**UPDATE**

This resource works better: [CSS browser/OS selectors with JS](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

Comment: it's picked up by opera 9.2 too

Comment: Yes, it's picked up by all webkit enabled browsers, so Chrome, Opera and Safari are the most popular webkit browsers.

Comment: Opera uses Presto, not webkit afaik.

Comment: Opera now uses webkit, Vivaldi (ex Opera) uses presto, they forked.

Answer (score 8):

There are some browser hacks available for targeting a specific browser,some of them will work on all the versions of the browser,and some one them not.

Here is the list of some the Google Chromes's hacks:

### WebKit hack:

```
.selector:not(*:root) {}
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Safari**:***All the versions***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***
- **Android**:***All the versions***

### Supports Hacks:

```
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {}
```

Google Chrome 28,and Google Chrome > 28, Opera 14 and Opera > 14

- **Google Chrome**:***28 and Later***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***

### Property/Value Hacks:

```
.selector { (;property: value;); }
.selector { [;property: value;]; }
```

Google Chrome 28,and Google Chrome < 28, Opera 14 and Opera > 14,and Safari 7 and Less than 7.
 - **Google Chrome**:***28 and Before***
 - **Safari**:***7 and Before***
 - **Opera *:14 and Later***

### JavaScript Hacks:1

```
var isChromium = !!window.chrome;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***
- **Android**:***4.0.4***

### JavaScript Hacks:2 {Webkit}

```
var isWebkit = 'WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Safari**:***3 and Later***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***

### JavaScript Hacks:3

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***14 and Later***

### Media Query Hacks:1

```
@media \\0 screen {}
```

- **Google Chrome**:***22 to 28***
- **Safari**:***7 and Later***

### Media Query Hacks:2

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { .selector {} }
```

- **Google Chrome**:***29 and Later***
- **Opera**:***16 and Later***

For more information please visit [this website](http://browserhacks.com/)