# Radio button background goes white in Windows Chrome when using -webkit-backface-visibility. Any workarounds?

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, radio-button, chromium

There's a bug in Windows Chrome that makes a radio button's background turn white when its parent is both out of the document flow and has `-webkit-backface-visibility` applied.

Here it is in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/misterkeg/uMajC/

I'm using `-webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden` to get around the WebKit transition flicker bug.

This problem also occurs if I use the `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` fix instead, so it seems to kick in whenever hardware acceleration is active.

Overriding the input's `-webkit-backface-visibility` to `visible` doesn't help either.

Are there any known workarounds to this? I've filed a [Chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119698) but would like to know if there are any ways around it in the meantime.

Comment: I've seen similar problems on some but not all buttons and radio buttons in some dialogs of a site I'm working on. No -webkit-backface-visibility involved. I have several *very* similar dialogs in my site; oddly, some of them have this problem and some don't. I'm afraid what I'm working on is too complex to post here, and still under development so I can't just provide a link. But it is worth knowing it probably has nothing to do with -webkit-backface-visibility, and can affect buttons as well as radio buttons. What they have in common is curved edges.

Comment: (by "very similar dialogs", I mean similar to one another, not to the original poster's)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the same problem but in different context, so might be it's not a problem with -webkit-backface-visiblity but with several combinations of things. In my case the problem arises when the page with the radio buttons contains a google maps like map (a propietary one, I haven't found what exactly in the map causes the problem) and is displayed inside an iframe.
If I hide the map with the inspector the radio buttons look ok, or if I view the page directly, not inside the iframe.

The only workaround I've found is in this page from CSS ninja: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css.

In summary, this is the solution (there is a live demo linked from the page I've mentioned, http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/):

**HTML**

```
<label for="input1" class="radio_image">
 <input type="radio" name="input" id="input1" />
 <span>Option 1</span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/*we hide the real radio button*/
.radio_image input[type=radio] {
  position:absolute;opacity:0;
}
/*we assign the span a background image
  which is a capture of the actual radio button*/
.radio_image input[type=radio] + span {
  background-image: url("radio-button.gif");
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.6em;
}
/*if radio is checked we change the background
  image to one with a checked radio button (it can be
  done with a sprite type background too): */
.radio_image input[type=radio]:checked + span {
  background-image: url("radio-button-checked.gif");
}
```

As the span is inside the label, clicking on it will have the same effect as clicking on the radio button itself, so the radio button still works ok.

I am working in a developement enviroment so I can´t post you the url, but with the code and the links above I think it's easy to see.

If you want to target just Chrome, you can try the solution provided in this post:
[Can you target Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447511/can-you-target-google-chrome-yes-you-can)

I hope it helps, I don't like such a complicated way to render just a simple radio button, in my case I've used it in the only page having that problem in my site and it has worked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with a form opened over a google map, but I solved hiding the map :P

Answer (score 2):

Better solution w/out having to use images:

Wrap the radio element in a div, and set that div's overflow to hidden, and border-radius to 100px. Then set the radio input to display block, and no margin. This worked for me:

Markup:

```
<div class="radio_contain">
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.radio_contain {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
.radio_contain input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution that doesn't use images ( nor radio css edits ).
The solution results in a round white circle around the radio button ( if your design can tolerate that ) try this:

html:

```
<span class='radioWrap'><input type='radio'...></span>
```

css:

```
.radioWrap{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px 3px 1px 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

That is it.