# White background on radio button on chrome

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome

I have a `white square background` on a radio button. This issue can be reproduced only of `Windows plus Chrome`. I tried many options trying to remove this issue but the issue still persists. Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X4QYm/)** for the issue. Is there anywork around to solve this issue.

Comment: Check this post.This may be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151523/radio-buttons-show-unwanted-white-background-in-chrome-firefox-is-fine

Answer (score 1):

This was a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119698) in chrome. I would recommend you update to the latest version of chrome. They seemed to have the bug resolved.

However in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4QYm/) you shared, I can see the white background around the radio button. I think it's probably because of the

```
-webkit-backface-visibility
```

applied to the container div.

I just added:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

and I don't see the white square now. Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X4QYm/9/).

@Jerin suggested you might also use a sprite image as a placeholder for the span on the radio button which would cover the white background on the radio button.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838583/radio-button-background-goes-white-in-windows-chrome-when-using-webkit-backface) post also might come in handy but I think they have resolved the issue in the latest versions of google chrome.

Hope it helps.

Comment: FYI. Your demo doesnt work in chrome. Which version are you using. - @Vivek Pradhan

Comment: I am using the Version 27.0.1453.94 m for chrome right now and the demo seems to be working fine on my browser.

Comment: It seems Chrome reverted to buggy version and has same problem with background in Version 31.0.1650.2 dev-m.