# Radio buttons show unwanted white background in Chrome. Firefox is fine

Tags: css, google-chrome, radio-button

In Google Chrome, radio buttons show a unwanted white background around the circle. This is not shown in Firefox as intended.

Please check these images.
[image]

And her is the direct link of the page having the issue (check in Firefox and Chrome)
https://my.infocaptor.com/dash/mt.php?pa=hr_dashboard3_503c135bce6f4

Any CSS tricks that I can apply for Chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838583/radio-button-background-goes-white-in-windows-chrome-when-using-webkit-backface

Comment: I saw that question but there was no solution

Comment: I don't see the background issue in Chrome - is this resolved?

Comment: A solution would be to use custom inputs

Comment: zenkaty, the issue is still there. What version of chrome are you using? Mine is 21.0

Comment: Did you resolve this? The radio buttons in your link look fine in Chrome.

Comment: no it still exists. I have to now revert to white backgrounds or place the radio button in a white background box

Comment: Same issue here (Google Chrome 28).

Answer (score 1):

this is a [known](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119698) Bug in Chrome which does not have real workarounds.

The only option I see and use at this point of time is to use a sprite sheet with images of the check boxes. I made a fiddle to show it to you with some random sprite I found on the internet:

[Workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/hannesmolsen/pSfeP/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" />
    <label for="r1"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
<p />
    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rr" />
    <label for="r2"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#show {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    /* Uncomment this to only see the working radio button */
    /* display:none; */
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(http://d3pr5r64n04s3o.cloudfront.net/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(http://d3pr5r64n04s3o.cloudfront.net/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) -57px top no-repeat;
}
```

[image: Radiobuttons with sprite]

You could create your own sprite with radio buttons in your desired design...

Hope that helps, if you have any more questions, let me know.

-Hannes

Comment: Oh, and if you want to use that only for chrome browsers, this post seems very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447511/can-you-target-google-chrome-yes-you-can

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the radio element in a div, and set that div's overflow to hidden, and border-radius to 100px. Then set the radio input to display block, and no margin. This worked for me:

Markup:

```
<div class="radio_contain">
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.radio_contain {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
.radio_contain input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had this same problem and it took me a while to figure it out, so I'm posting this if someone else has the same problem. 
I figured it out quite accidentally really. I was looking at something else and zoomed in on page using ctrl and scroll, and saw that radio button didn't have white background any more (and looked better). So I just put:

```
zoom: 0.999;
```

in right css class and that fixed it for me.