# Is it possible to target Chrome only, not all Webkit powered browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, media-queries

Vaguely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447511/can-you-target-google-chrome), but not quite the same. I'd like to target Chrome ONLY, without targeting Safari.

I used the following media query, but it targets both Chrome and Safari:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) { 
    h1, h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Chrome does a great job at rendering the header elements in bold even though a bold version of the font I'm using doesn't exist. Safari... not so much. Hence the super specific targeting. For reference, the font is [Cody Star](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Codystar).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you target Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447511/can-you-target-google-chrome)

Comment: Yup, I mention that and link to it in the first sentence of my own question. The difference is I was attempting to target Chrome only, whereas the question (though worded the same) was looking to target both Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are browser-specific CSS hacks that might work for this problem now, but they certainly aren't supported.

IMHO, your best bet is to add a class to the body tag using JavaScript that reads your navigator.userAgent and use that class (body.chrome for example) to target Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Safari,Chrome,Opera all of them are [Web-kit](https://www.webkit.org) browsers, so it's very difficult to find a CSS or media query hack to target this browsers specifically,

but here is a JavaScript code that will target the Google Chrome, 
not all the versions of Google Chrome,But Chrome 14 and later.

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

if you want to know more information,please refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392027/1883401),for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447511/can-you-target-google-chrome)